# Android numberDecimal, considering locale in xml layout

Tags: android, xml, decimal, locale

For e.g. an EditText it is normal to specify android:inputType="numberDecimal" for a text field supposed to contain a decimal number. But this assumes that '.' is used as the decimal separator and in some countries ',' is used instead. Is it possible to specify in xml that the users locale needs to be considered or do I have to do it manually in my code?

Comment: I have the same problem. Hopefully someone knows the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is known bug, [see here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2626) for more information.

A possible workaround is to set `android:inputType="numberDecimal"` (so the digit keyboard will be opend) and `android:digits="0123456789.,"` (so the comma can be entered into the `EditText`). Then add a `TextChangedListener` and do something like  `Double.parseDouble(editable.toString().replace(',', '.'));` in `afterTextChanged`.